# WSO2 + WCF Data Services

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

For our project we use WSO2 products, for data access was selected WCF Data Services technology by Microsoft. How we can generate proxy service for our WCF Data Service use WSO2 ESB or WSO2 Data Service Server?

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you are going to access WSO2 DSS/ESB from your WCF service? 
Or do you want to create a proxy service for your WCF service?

Answer (score 1):

Use WSO2 ESB to expose your proxy services.

Comment: Please write it as comment.